# How to to customize the user attribute page in the keycloak admin console

Tags: keycloak

I would customize the user attributes page of the keycloak 21.1.1 admin console. Before this release simply I created the admin theme and I overridden the user-attributes.html page. Now that the admin console has changed it is no longer possible. How can I do this?